# Python - Control window with pywinauto while the window is minimized or hidden

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to create a script in python with pywinauto to automatically install notepad++ in the background (hidden or minimized), notepad++ is just an example since I will edit it to work with other software.

**Problem:**

The problem is that I want to do it while the installer is hidden or minimized, but if I move my mouse the script will stop working.

**Question:**

How can I execute this script and make it work, while the notepad++ installer is hidden or minimized.

**This is my code so far**:

```
import sys, os, pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()

app = pywinauto.Application().Start(r'npp.6.8.3.Installer.exe')

Wizard = app['Installer Language']

Wizard.NextButton.Click()

Wizard = app['Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup']

Wizard.Wait('visible')

Wizard['Welcome to the Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup'].Wait('ready')
Wizard.NextButton.Click()

Wizard['License Agreement'].Wait('ready')
Wizard['I &Agree'].Click()

Wizard['Choose Install Location'].Wait('ready')
Wizard.Button2.Click()

Wizard['Choose Components'].Wait('ready')
Wizard.Button2.Click()

Wizard['Create Shortcut on Desktop'].Wait('enabled').CheckByClick()
Wizard.Install.Click()

Wizard['Completing the Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup'].Wait('ready', timeout=30)
Wizard['CheckBox'].Wait('enabled').Click()
Wizard.Finish.Click()
Wizard.WaitNot('visible')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Wizard['Create Shortcut on Desktop'].wait('enabled').check_by_click()
```

`check_by_click()` uses `click_input()` method that moves real mouse cursor and performs a realistic click.

Use `check()` method instead.

[EDIT] If the installer doesn't handle `BM_SETCHECK` properly the workaround may look so:

```
checkbox = Wizard['Create Shortcut on Desktop'].wait('enabled')
if checkbox.get_check_state() != pywinauto.win32defines.BST_CHECKED:
    checkbox.click()
```

I will fix it in the next pywinauto release by creating methods `check_by_click` and `check_by_click_input` respectively.

---

[EDIT 2]
I tried your script with my fix and it works perfectly (and very fast) with and without mouse moves. Win7 x64, 32-bit Python 2.7, pywinauto 0.6.x, run as administrator.

```
import sys
import os
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="win32").start(r'npp.6.8.3.Installer.exe')

Wizard = app['Installer Language']

Wizard.minimize()
Wizard.NextButton.click()

Wizard = app['Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup']

Wizard.wait('visible')
Wizard.minimize()

Wizard['Welcome to the Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup'].wait('ready')
Wizard.NextButton.click()

Wizard.minimize()
Wizard['License Agreement'].wait('ready')
Wizard['I &Agree'].click()

Wizard.minimize()
Wizard['Choose Install Location'].wait('ready')
Wizard.Button2.click()

Wizard.minimize()
Wizard['Choose Components'].wait('ready')
Wizard.Button2.click()

Wizard.minimize()
checkbox = Wizard['Create Shortcut on Desktop'].wait('enabled')
if checkbox.get_check_state() != pywinauto.win32defines.BST_CHECKED:
    checkbox.click()
Wizard.Install.click()

Wizard['Completing the Notepad++ v6.8.3 Setup'].wait('ready', timeout=30)
Wizard.minimize()
Wizard['CheckBox'].wait('enabled').click()
Wizard.Finish.click()
Wizard.wait_not('visible')
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... when I execute the script if I move the mouse it will stop and not click any button. And If I dont move the mouse it will stop in 'Choose Install Location', if I move it will stop when I move the mouse.

Comment: I just find out that if I have the mouse on the window without moving the mouse, the script will stop working, but if I have the mouse not on the window, then it will work, so my problem now is that I hadn't figure out yet how to hide the window. Can you help me on that?

Comment: It works for me with `Wizard.Minimize()`. I've edited the answer with the updated script. If you still stuck there, please provide the stdout/stderr.

Comment: Carlos, please, show the exact place where the script stops.
I guess it happens on a `.Wait('ready')`. Here `ready` means that the window is visible and enabled - [doc](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=wait#pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.Wait)
As you are trying to hide the window you may use `.Wait('enabled')` instead.
Although I do not know why it affects by mouse. In any case, the list of actions and the traceback will be useful.

Comment: It seems that the script is working pretty good now, I don't know what it was. Just one more question if it is possible, there is a way of hiding the window completely, and not show in the taskbar?

Comment: by the way, I'm using Windows 10 Pro x64, python 3.4, pywinauto 0.5.3 as administrator

Comment: Carlos, I could not find how to hide the window from the taskbar. If you could, it would be great feature request! ;-)

Comment: Well, thank you for all your help! You helped me a lot! If I find a way of hiding it I will tell you ;)

Comment: The following thread could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425038/hide-window-from-ms-windows-taskbar I cannot get it to work yet, but it seems like right direction.

Comment: This is another useful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933219/hide-window-from-taskbar-without-using-ws-ex-toolwindow

Comment: OK, I figured it out and will implement `HideFromTaskbar` method of the `DialogWrapper`.

Comment: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/commit/46cd14110abd309dd72a172bb0879931b2f84d0b

Comment: The Hide taskbar function it's working, I just tested. Also I tried     `win32functions.ShowWindow(self, win32defines.SW_HIDE)`, the window hides but the automation doesn't work. Is there any way to hide it like that and still press the buttons, etc.?