# How can I send text when the window is minimized?

Tags: python, pywinauto, pyautogui

I have tried using python libraries: pyautogui + pwinauto.
But to no avail.
Once the window is minimized the text is no longer send.

code snippet:

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.hotkey('win')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite('notepad')
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('test aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccc ')
```

Comment: According to the [pyautogui docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#keyboard-functions) you can't do this: "Key presses go to wherever the keyboard cursor is at function-calling time."

Comment: Which one? Your program's window or the target window?

Comment: target window, in this case 'notepad'.

Comment: The answer looks correct and still not accepted. Sorry to remind about such old thread. Just updated the answer for latest pywinauto version.

Answer (score 7):

pywinauto can send text to a minimized window.

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application(backend="win32").start('notepad.exe')
app.UntitledNotepad.minimize()
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.set_text('some text\nsecond line')
```

`type_keys()` method requires a control to be in focus. But `set_text` sends `WM_SETTEXT` message by window handle, so focus is not required.

Another example of script dealing with minimized window: [Python - Control window with pywinauto while the window is minimized or hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846550/python-control-window-with-pywinauto-while-the-window-is-minimized-or-hidden)