# Automated testing of InstallAnywhere wizard

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, installanywhere

I need to automate installation process of some product, but it has to be exactly installation through passing `InstallAnywhere wizard` (it's kinda GUI testing of installation process, so silent install won't work). 
Any suggestion how to do this?

I guess the main problem is that installation file (*.exe) is just extractor which extract required files to temp folder and then run java application.

Comment: Which language do you prefer for writing the tests? Java only? Or maybe Python is acceptable?

Comment: Java is preferred, but if you have good decision with Python I would like to look at this and consider.

Comment: We have an example of installer GUI testing automation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846550/python-control-window-with-pywinauto-while-the-window-is-minimized-or-hidden But for Java part of the installer it wouldn't work I think. But we have an experimental solution (will be released in March) that may work. So what is about early testing?

Comment: Since I have no options I would try it.

Comment: One more detail: do you plan to test your installer in a cross-platform way? Or one OS only?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take it into account. I can suggest Windows only solution for now. You may try LDTP for cross-platform GUI but it's not easy to learn.

Comment: I hope to do it in cross-platform, but different Windows versions would be a good start.

Comment: Many other tools are very platform dependent. We have long-term plans to extend pywinauto to Linux and maybe OS X. But now it's Windows only. Okay, I'll try to provide the info for early testing.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) to test it on Windows. Java part of the installer may require new "UIA" back-end which will be released in March. For early testing you may try the following steps:

1. Install [pyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) and [comtypes](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes) by `pip install pypiwin32` and `pip install comtypes`.
2. Install [UIA branch of pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/UIA) by `python setup.py install`.

Try the following code:

```
import pywinauto
pywinauto.backend.activate('uia')

app = pywinauto.Application().start('your_installer_path.exe')
app.ApproximateMainWindowName.Wait('ready', timeout=15)
app.ApproximateMainWindowName.PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

`PrintControlIdentifiers` output is a hint for further steps. There are possible access names for the controls on the window. Only basic functionality like `ClickInput()` and `TypeKeys('something')` should work for now.

Available methods for the control can be advised here:

```
app.MainWindow.OKButton.WrapperObject(). # methods list can be displayed here in IDLE or Visual Studio Python Tools
app.MainWindow.OKButton.WrapperObject().ClickInput() # code for debugging
#app.MainWindow.OKButton.ClickInput() # it works the same way, for production code
```

Feel free to ask more help if something doesn't work.

Python scripts may require running as Administrator to have an access to the GUI. Or add manifest for python.exe with `uiAccess="true"`.

Comment: I've tried it and looks like it doesn't work with java app. The start window (InstallAnywhere extracter) can be worked with, but the actual wizard part cannot be handled and fails with timeout on waiting.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how it works, but seems like there is a link between app object and exe-file, if so the problem probably is here, because the java app is not run from this exe-file.

Comment: I've tried to connect by process id, and it doesn't help so much. The wizard has been found by title at least, no controls are available inside though.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure, but what if [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-136191.html) would help? I've not dived into Java Accessibility yet. Just saved the link for future.

Comment: The best scenario would be "just install or run Java Access Bridge and enjoy", the worst case may require implementation of new back-end for pywinauto. I'm afraid the second one is most probable.

Comment: I've found [how to enable Java Access Bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html) in Control Panel. It's easy and doesn't require to install anything.

Comment: Hmm... I've enabled Java Access Bridge (JAB) too, and I can see elements on Java demo apps with Inspect.exe in UI Automation mode. I need to take a look at some InstallAnywhere example.

Comment: Just in case. If you use IDLE or other IDE, you probably need to reload Python interpreter after enabling JAB and restarting wizard.

Comment: Hmm... Not all Java apps are equally accessible by UIA. JavaFX samples look OK, but owner-drawn Java2D and similar samples have no accessibility info. You may ask InstallAnywhere tech support about accessibility features in a wizard.