# PyWinAuto trouble clicking the Next Button

Tags: python, pywinauto

This code gets the first window from InstallShield.

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import findwindows

app = application.Application()

app.start("MyInstallShieldApp.exe")

time.sleep(15)

hwnd = findwindows.find_windows(title=u"InstallShield Wizard", class_name="MsiDialogCloseClass")
print ("|", str(hwnd), "|")
dlg = app.Window_(handle=hwnd).Wait("enabled", timeout=25, retry_interval=0.5)
```

Now I want to click the Next button. Swapy says that the Next button has the text '&Next >' and the Button number is 1. But none of these click statements have any effect.

```
dlg.Click("Next")

dlg.Click(coords=(977, 711))

dlg.Click(button="left")
```

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846550/python-control-window-with-pywinauto-while-the-window-is-minimized-or-hidden

Comment: Have you tried to generate `Click()` code using SWAPY? It can be done by popup menu at the button element in the tree.

Comment: One more useful thread about attribute access: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/120

Answer (score 1):

You misapply `Click` method. It has the next signatire - `Click(button=u'left', pressed=u'', coords=(0, 0), double=False, absolute=False)`

To click a button, `click` should be performed on the button object. So you shoud navigate to the button at first.

In your case the code may look something like:
`dlg['&Next >'].Click()`

Again, please do not guess, read the [docs](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.html?highlight=click#pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper.Click) and see the [examples](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/master/examples)