# Installing programs using python script

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pywinauto

I'm trying to write a script which downloads and installs notepad++ on windows, unfortunately, I can't find a way to install notepad++ automatically.
I used:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
fsv =Application(backend="uia").start("notepad++.exe")
fsv.InstallDialog.NextButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.IAgreeRadioButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.Edit.Wait('ready', timeout=30).type_keys(os.getcwd() + "\Notepad++", with_spaces=True)
fsv.InstallDialog.InstallButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.FinishButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Control window with pywinauto while the window is minimized or hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846550/python-control-window-with-pywinauto-while-the-window-is-minimized-or-hidden)

Comment: Also Notepad++ installer should have silent option like `-s` to operate without GUI. Just start the installer in `cmd.exe` with `/?` parameter to get help for all options.