# Python - Interact with program´s GUI OFFSCREEN

Tags: python, automation, background, pyautogui, pywinauto

I know this is too greedy, but i want to make python interact with a program´s user interface but on the background, so that i can still use my computer while the code runs. I am currently using pywinauto and pyautogui. So I can´t work while the code is running because my mouse and keybord are being manipulated. Does someone know how to make my code manipulate a "second" mouse and keyboard on the background while I use my mouse and keyboard to do other things?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is a remote execution (on dedicated server or on virtual machine). All known recipes for pywinauto are collected in [the Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

More complicated way is trying to use silent methods of pywinauto that don't require active desktop. This is partially mentioned in the above guide, but requires deep knowledge of pywinauto and your application structure. One of the examples was discussed on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32847266/3648361 This way is not possible for many kinds of applications.

I've never heard about "second mouse/keyboard" approach. Not sure it's technically possible at all.